# Add a HTML property to a DOMElement using php DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

How can I add a HTML property to an existing DOMElement using php DOMDocument?

If I use [DOMElement::setAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/de/domelement.setattribute.php) and leave the value empty like

```
$node->setAttribute('my-property', '');
```

it always results in an empty attribute `<span my-property="">...</span>` 
instead of a real property `<span my-property>...</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a property to an existing DOMElement using [DOMElement::setAttributeNode](http://php.net/manual/de/domelement.setattributenode.php).

If `$node` is a DOMElement of a DOMDocument `$dom`, you can write

```
$domAttr = $dom->createAttribute('my-property');
$node->setAttributeNode($domAttr);
```

This will result in `<span my-property>...</span>`